# Como resolver Erro Catchable fatal error ao tentar mostrar mensagens

Tags: php

Tenho uma página onde verifico se o usuário preencheu todos os campos de um `form` mas ao tentar mostrar as mensagens para o usuário o `script` me retorna um erro, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
class SendEmail
{
   private $nome;
   private $email;
   private $telefone;
   private $cidade;
   private $uf;
   private $assunto;
   private $mensagem;
   private $receive_mail;

   public function __construct($data)
   {

    $this->receive_mail = "webdevelopermgri@gmail.com";
      try
      {
        if (count($data) sendMail();

      } catch (Exception $e) {
            return json_encode(array('success'=>'0','errors'=>$e->getMessage()));
      }    

     }

     public function sendMail()
     {
      $subject = $this->assunto;
      $body = "From {$this->nome}, \n\n{nl2br($this->mensagem)}";
      $headers = 'From: ' . $this->email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $this->email . "\r\n" .
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

       if (mail($this->receive_mail, $this->assunto, $body, $headers)) {
          return json_encode(array('success'=>'1','message'=>'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!'));
       } else {
          throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro no envio da mensagem, por favor, tente mais tarde.");
       }
     }
}

if ($_POST) {
    // Aqui ele retornará um JSON com os erros ou a mensagem de sucesso
    echo json_encode(new SendMail($_POST)); 
}
```

E a mensagem completa é essa:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class SendEmail could not be converted to string in /home/anc/public_html/anc/sendEmail.php on line 84
```

O problema é que estou tentando mostrar um `Objeto` como `string` pelo que li no manual do `php`, mas não consegui resolver.

Comment: A mensagem do email, deveria ser acessivel via propriedade ou método de um objeto e não só pelo construtor. `print new SendEmail($_POST);`

Comment: Poderia colocar o construtor dessa classe?

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta com o código completo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O problema da linha `84` é o `print`, que tenta converter o objeto para string antes de imprimí-lo.

Objetos em PHP não podem ser convertidos para string, a não ser que o mesmo implementem o método mágico `__toString`.

Exemplo:

```
class MyClass
{
    protected $minha_informacao = 'Informação importante';

     public function __toString()
     {
          return (string) $this->minha_informacao;
     }
}
```

Você pode convertê-los simplesmente fazendo assim:

```
$obj = new MyClass;

echo $obj;

$string = (string) $obj;
```

Se quiser ver os valores de um objeto, você deve fazer o que está descrito na resposta do @rray

Vi também que você quer converter um objeto para o formato `json`. Isso no PHP só é possível usando a função `json_encode`.

Vale ressaltar que, em classes que não implementem a interface `JsonSerializable` essa serialização para `json` não ocorre de maneira desejada. A interface obriga sua classe a conter o método `jsonSerialize`, que se encarregará de "mostrar" à função `json_encode` como aquele objeto será serializado.

Então faça assim:

```
class SendMail implements JsonSerializable
{
   public function jsonSerialize()
   {
       return $this->dados_que_quero_serializar;
   }
}
```

Assim é possível fazer:

```
 echo json_encode(new SendMail($_POST));
```

Se quiser unir o útil e o agradável para seu objeto ser "impresso" sem ter que alterar a forma que você imprime, poderá combinar as duas formas que te ensinei acima:

```
class SendMail implements JsonSerializable

{
     public function jsonSerialize()
     {
          return array('email' => $this->email, 'nome' => $this->nome);
     }

     public function __toString()
     {
           return (string) json_encode($this);
     }
}
```

A saída disso será:

```
echo new SendMail($_POST);
```

Saída:

```
 {"nome": "Wallace Maxters", "email" : "wallacemaxters@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Olá, @Wallace Maxters, obrigado pelas excelentes dicas, resolveu meu problema, valeu.

Comment: @adventistapr, sua classe vai ficar "mais bonita" e ainda de quebra aprendeu uma interface nova, que é nativa do php

Answer (score 6):

Para exibir a estrutura de um array, objeto ou outro tipo que não seja uma escalar use as funções, `print_r()` ou `var_dump()`.

O construtor da classe não deve retornar nada além do objeto o que já é feito automaticamente, não faz sentido nenhum retornar outra coisa. Você chama a criação de um objeto para manipular e recebe um a string. É mesma coisa que pedir em um restaurante  uma pizza e o garçom trazer uma salada.

```
 public function __construct($data){
    $this->receive_mail = "webdevelopermgri@gmail.com";
    try {
        if (count($data) sendMail();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
       //return estranho no construtor
       return json_encode(array('success'=>'0','errors'=>$e->getMessage()));
    }    
}
```

Ao chamar essa linha você espera um objeto email ou um json?

```
//essa linha retorna um objeto ou json? o que esperar?
$email = new SendMail($_POST);
//a linha a baixo seria o mais adequado.
$json = json_encode($email->getMessage());
```

### Exemplo Simplificado do problema:

```
class Email{
    private $message;

    public function __construct($msg){
        $this->message = $msg;
        return 'WTF? O.o';
    }

    public function getMessage(){
        return $this->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Exemplo 1

```
$msg = 'Into the void';
$email = new Email($msg);
var_dump($email);
```

A saida será:

```
object(Email)[1]
  private 'message' => string 'Into the void' (length=13)
```

Um `return` no construtor nunca é executado, apenas deixa o entendimendo método pra la de estranho. Você chamou/pediu a construção de um objeto email porque receberia algo diferente?

A partir do php5.4 é possível criar um objeto e já invocar um método apenas adicionando parenteses em torno do new class. A outra solução é criar uma nova variável ou chamar o retorno do método direto em um função ex: `json_econde()`.

Exemplo 2, solução:

```
$msg = 'Into the void';
echo (new Email($msg))->getMessage();
```

Ou ainda:

```
$msg = 'Into the void';
$email = new Email($msg);
echo json_encode($email->getMessage());
```

Saida:

```
Into the void
```